# What means bold in the achievement button?

Tags: discussion

For the first time, I see this:

[image]

For which reason "blender axis to angle" is in bold? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new entry that you have not yet opened and is used to highlight unread messages.

As soon as you click on it, the entry will be displayed again as usual.